# Streaming video from an external service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stream

I am working on a project (server side) where i need to stream data (videos, large files) to clients.

This worked perfect using `ByteRangeStreamContent`, as i was serving files from disk and could create a seekable stream (`FileStream`).

```
    if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
    {
                try
                {
                        HttpResponseMessage partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
                        partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(fs, Request.Headers.Range, mediaType);
                        return partialResponse;
                }
                catch (InvalidByteRangeException invalidByteRangeException)
                {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(invalidByteRangeException);
                }
     }
     else
     {
                    response.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
                    return response;
     }
```

But, i moved the file provider from disk to an external service. The service allows me to get chunks of data (Range{0}-{1}).

Of course, it's not possible to download whole file in memory and then use a `MemoryStream` for `ByteRangeStreamContent` because of the obvious reasons (too many concurrent downloads will consume all the available memory at some point).

I found this article https://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/progressive-download-support-in-asp-net-web-api/ where the author says:

> A change request I got for my library was to support reading only the
>   necessary data and sending that out rather than opening a stream for
>   the full data. I wasn’t sure what this would buy until the user
>   pointed out they are reading their resource data from a WCF stream
>   which does not support seeking and would need to read the whole stream
>   into a MemoryStream in order to allow the library to generate the
>   output.
>
> That limitation still exists in this specific object but there is a
>   workaround. Instead of using a ByteRangeStreamContent, you could
>   instead use a ByteArrayContent object instead. Since the majority of
>   RANGE requests will be for a single start and end byte, you could pull
>   the range from the HttpRequestMessage, retrieve only the bytes you
>   need and send it back out as a byte stream. You’ll also need to add
>   the CONTENT-RANGE header and set the response code to 206
>   (PartialContent) but this could be a viable alternative (though I
>   haven’t tested it) for users who do not want or can’t easily get a
>   compliant stream object.

So, my question basically is: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it.

Here's how:

Custom implementation of a `stream`:

```
public class BufferedHTTPStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly Int64 cacheLength = 4000000;
        private const Int32 noDataAvaiable = 0;
        private MemoryStream stream = null;
        private Int64 currentChunkNumber = -1;
        private Int64? length;
        private Boolean isDisposed = false;
        private Func<long, long, Stream> _getStream;
        private Func<long> _getContentLength;

        public BufferedHTTPStream(Func<long, long, Stream> streamFunc, Func<long> lengthFunc)
        {
            _getStream = streamFunc;
            _getContentLength = lengthFunc;
        }

        public override Boolean CanRead
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override Boolean CanWrite
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override Boolean CanSeek
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override Int64 Length
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                if (length == null)
                {
                    length = _getContentLength();
                }
                return length.Value;
            }
        }

        public override Int64 Position
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                Int64 streamPosition = (stream != null) ? stream.Position : 0;
                Int64 position = (currentChunkNumber != -1) ? currentChunkNumber * cacheLength : 0;

                return position + streamPosition;
            }
            set
            {
                EnsureNotDisposed();
                EnsurePositiv(value, "Position");
                Seek(value);
            }
        }

        public override Int64 Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();
            switch (origin)
            {
                case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                    break;
                case SeekOrigin.Current:
                    offset = Position + offset;
                    break;
                default:
                    offset = Length + offset;
                    break;
            }

            return Seek(offset);
        }

        private Int64 Seek(Int64 offset)
        {
            Int64 chunkNumber = offset / cacheLength;

            if (currentChunkNumber != chunkNumber)
            {
                ReadChunk(chunkNumber);
                currentChunkNumber = chunkNumber;
            }

            offset = offset - currentChunkNumber * cacheLength;

            stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return Position;
        }

        private void ReadNextChunk()
        {
            currentChunkNumber += 1;
            ReadChunk(currentChunkNumber);
        }

        private void ReadChunk(Int64 chunkNumberToRead)
        {
            Int64 rangeStart = chunkNumberToRead * cacheLength;

            if (rangeStart >= Length) { return; }

            Int64 rangeEnd = rangeStart + cacheLength - 1;
            if (rangeStart + cacheLength > Length)
            {
                rangeEnd = Length - 1;
            }

            if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); }
            stream = new MemoryStream((int)cacheLength);

            var responseStream = _getStream(rangeStart, rangeEnd);

            responseStream.Position = 0;
            responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
            responseStream.Close();

            stream.Position = 0;
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();

            base.Close();
            if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); }
            isDisposed = true;
        }

        public override Int32 Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();

            EnsureNotNull(buffer, "buffer");
            EnsurePositiv(offset, "offset");
            EnsurePositiv(count, "count");

            if (buffer.Length - offset < count) { throw new ArgumentException("count"); }

            if (stream == null) { ReadNextChunk(); }

            if (Position >= Length) { return noDataAvaiable; }

            if (Position + count > Length)
            {
                count = (Int32)(Length - Position);
            }

            Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            Int32 totalBytesRead = bytesRead;
            count -= bytesRead;

            while (count > noDataAvaiable)
            {
                ReadNextChunk();
                offset = offset + bytesRead;
                bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                count -= bytesRead;
                totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
            }

            return totalBytesRead;

        }

        public override void SetLength(Int64 value)
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            EnsureNotDisposed();
        }

        private void EnsureNotNull(Object obj, String name)
        {
            if (obj != null) { return; }
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
        private void EnsureNotDisposed()
        {
            if (!isDisposed) { return; }
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("BufferedHTTPStream");
        }
        private void EnsurePositiv(Int32 value, String name)
        {
            if (value > -1) { return; }
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name);
        }
        private void EnsurePositiv(Int64 value, String name)
        {
            if (value > -1) { return; }
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name);
        }
        private void EnsureNegativ(Int64 value, String name)
        {
            if (value < 0) { return; }
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var fs = new BufferedHTTPStream((start, end) => 
    {
        // return stream from external service
    }, () => 
    {
       // return stream length from external service
    });

    HttpResponseMessage partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(fs, Request.Headers.Range, mediaType);
    partialResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new     ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                            {
                                FileName = fileName
                            };
    return partialResponse;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn’t work for me. Tried to use in Asp.Net MVC application (.Net framework 4.6.2), url to azure blob storage video file. In front end simple html video tag with path to controller method as  source and type ‘video/mp4’.