# RestSharp: how to get only a certain range of bytes from Request targeting a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stream, restsharp

I have the piece of API below:

```
[Route("api/v1/video")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVideoContent()
{
    const string fileName = "video.mp4";
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:57243/");

    var request = new RestRequest($"Assets/{fileName}");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "video/mp4");

    var range = Request.Headers.Range.Ranges.First();
    var from = range.From;
    var to = range.To ?? 10;

    request.AddHeader("Range", $"bytes={from}-{to}");

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    request.ResponseWriter = connectStream =>
    {
        connectStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    };

    await client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync(request);

    var httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse();
    httpResponse.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
    httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4");
    httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = fileName
    };

    return httpResponse;
}
```

Called by the piece of html below:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="/api/v1/video" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

The thing is that executing the code above does not give a `Stream`(`ConnectStream` behind) that would be limited accordingly to the `Range` header but rather the entire stream...

How can I get only a fraction of this file using the Range header?

This is just a PoC and I don't want to utilize the `File.OpenRead` or other cause it would defeat the entire purpose of reading a file using only the `RestClient`.

Note: Assets is just a folder in the ASP.NET solution.

Comment: Whatever is running at `localhost:57243` would have to respect the `Range` header and provide an appropriate response. Is that another API that you created?

Comment: @Dan Wilson, nope it's just the same API trying to get something in the asset folder. The stream I got actually containes the entirety of the file which is odd (regardless of the range given)...

Comment: @Dan Wilson it kinda makes sense nothing is implemented so it might be the case that file is subject to the simplest GET which takes the entirety of the folder I'm still surprised though that it's not supporting the range header natively...

Comment: Can you provide the code which is actually retrieving the file from the file system? Are you using `ByteRangeStreamContent` and providing it the `Range` header? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481926/3608792